# Toggle divs to display mutiple information boxes using buttons on the nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is what I have now...

```js
$("#contact").click(function() {
   if ( $( "#contact_div" ).length ) {
      $("#contact_div").remove();
   } else {
      var html='<div id="contact_div" class="contact-info"><p>Contact info</p></div>';
      $('body').append(html);
   }
   
});
$("#submission").click(function() {
   if ( $( "#submission_div" ).length ) {
      $("#submission_div").remove();
   } else {
      var html='<div id="submission_div" class="submission-methods"><p>submission methods</p></div>';
      $('body').append(html);
   }
});
$("#database").click(function() {
   if ( $( "#database_div" ).length ) {
      $("#database_div").remove();
   } else {
      var html='';
      $('body').append(html);
   }
});
$("#frequent").click(function() {
   if ( $( "#frequent_div" ).length ) {
      $("#frequent_div").remove();
   } else {
      var html='<div id="frequent_div" class="Freqeuent kick-codes"><p>frequent kick codes</p></div>';
      $('body').append(html);
   }
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
 background-image: url("images/mark-athena-2.png");
 background-color: #d4d4d4;
 
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: "blessed-facit-semibold", "arial Black", Arial;
 color: #999999;
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 14px;
}

nav {
 background-color: #514a79;
 height: 25px;
}

a:hover {
 color:#e3e3f2;
}
 
 /* color for link= #e3e3f2 */

div {
 height: 100px;
 width 150px;
 border: solid 1px;
 margin: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #e6e6e6;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Accelorator</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/accel-stylesheet.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cont.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a id="contact" href="#">Contact info</a>
      <a id="submission" href="#">Submission methods</a>
      <a id="database" href="#">Data base</a>
      <a id="frequent" href="#">Frequent kick codes</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="contact_div" class="contact-info">
       <p>Contact info</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="submission_div" class="submission-methods">
       <p>submission methods</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="frequent_div" class="Freqeuent kick-codes">
       <p>frequent kick codes</p> 
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Okay So when I click "Contact Info" on the Nav bar I want the "contact info div" to display or disappear or toggle... same for Submission methods, Data base, and Frequent kick codes. the divs should be able to be toggled to display information inside, and stay displayed until toggled off by the button that toggled them on...

So here is my HTML Code i have created for this project...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Accelorator</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/accel-stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>

    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Contact info</a>
      <a href="#">Submission methods</a>
      <a href="#">Data base</a>
      <a href="#">Frequent kick codes</a>

    </nav>

    <div class="contact-info">
       <p>Contact info</p> 
    </div>


    <div class="submission-methods">
       <p>submission methods</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="Freqeuent kick-codes">
       <p>frequent kick codes</p> 
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is my css

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #d4d4d4;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "blessed-facit-semibold", "arial Black", Arial;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 14px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #514a79;
    height: 25px;
}

a:hover {
    color:#e3e3f2;
}

    /* color for link= #e3e3f2 */

div {
    height: 100px;
    width 150px;
    border: solid 1px;
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery `.toggle` function, documentation and samples are available [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

You can give an 'id' to the individual navigation anchors, and associate a `click` event that with jQuery will toggle the `div` you want. I'd use `id` in all of them, but you can surely work with `class` too.

The sample code becomes some like:

```
<body>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a id="contact" href="#">Contact info</a>
      <a id="submission" href="#">Submission methods</a>
      <a id="database" href="#">Data base</a>
      <a id="frequent" href="#">Frequent kick codes</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="contact_div" class="contact-info">
       <p>Contact info</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="submission_div" class="submission-methods">
       <p>submission methods</p> 
    </div>

    <div id="frequent_div" class="Freqeuent kick-codes">
       <p>frequent kick codes</p> 
    </div>
</body>
```

The jQuery/javascript code looks like:

```
 $("#contact").click(function(){
    $("#contact_div").toggle();
 });
 $("#submission").click(function(){
    $("#submission_div").toggle();
 });
 $("#database").click(function(){
    $("#database_div").toggle();
 });
 $("#frequent").click(function(){
    $("#frequent_div").toggle();
 });
```

Two notes:
 1. the `database` section is missing in the original post
 2. you need to include the jQuery on the page, either you
 load it locally on your server, or include it via CDN, like:
 `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>`

For the second request on this, the code blocks would to be added/removed based on clicks. The jQuery method change, and for the full working solution you also need to correctly both import jquery, source the javascript code, and have an `document.ready` handler that will actually initialize the elements. The code looks like this (css remains unchanged).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>Accelorator</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/accel-stylesheet.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cont.js"></script>
    <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
               initialize();
            });
        </script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a id="contact" href="#">Contact info</a>
      <a id="submission" href="#">Submission methods</a>
      <a id="database" href="#">Data base</a>
      <a id="frequent" href="#">Frequent kick codes</a>
    </nav>

    <div id="contact_div" class="contact-info">
       <p>Contact info</p>
    </div>

    <div id="submission_div" class="submission-methods">
       <p>submission methods</p>
    </div>

    <div id="frequent_div" class="Freqeuent kick-codes">
       <p>frequent kick codes</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

with the js/cont.js as:

```
function initialize() {
    $("#contact").click(function() {
       if ( $( "#contact_div" ).length ) {
          $("#contact_div").remove();
       } else {
          var html='<div id="contact_div" class="contact-info"><p>Contact info</p></div>';
          $('body').append(html);
       }

    });
    $("#submission").click(function() {
       if ( $( "#submission_div" ).length ) {
          $("#submission_div").remove();
       } else {
          var html='<div id="submission_div" class="submission-methods"><p>submission methods</p></div>';
          $('body').append(html);
       }
    });
    $("#database").click(function() {
       if ( $( "#database_div" ).length ) {
          $("#database_div").remove();
       } else {
          var html='';
          $('body').append(html);
       }
    });
    $("#frequent").click(function() {
       if ( $( "#frequent_div" ).length ) {
          $("#frequent_div").remove();
       } else {
          var html='<div id="frequent_div" class="Freqeuent kick-codes"><p>frequent kick codes</p></div>';
          $('body').append(html);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: So is there a way to lets say if I click submission info first then contact info? the contact info would show under submission methods div? if that makes any sense?

Comment: @KaineBishop If what you are asking is how to append and display blocks based on when you click them, yes that's possible, still with jQuery. You would have to look then for `.append` and `.remove`.
Let me try a quick test on fiddle.

Comment: Here the new sample: note that the changes are substantial, in that 'append' will actually add a full piece of html code.

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/t2odcxq7/2/)

Comment: hmm its not working... i wonder if its cause im not linking the files correctly

Comment: I updated the answer, as I could not find a good way to copy/paste the full files onto jsFiddle. Basically, with jQuery, you will generally need to have a 'document.ready' handler that runs as soon as the page has finished loading, and then applies all of it's selectors/function bindings. That is what the `$(document).ready();` function is for. Creating an **initialize** function inside of **js/cont.js** makes things more compact and logically organized.

Comment: so if i didn't want to divs to show up initially how would I do that?

Comment: As it is, you can delete them from the html itself, as the javascript code will create them on the fly for you.

Comment: so would it be something like in java code  $('*[data-container]').hide();?

Comment: Careful in differentiating between what the first answer does (hide/show of existing elements in the DOM) and what the second problem/answer does (add/delete elements on the fly to the DOM). If you have specific questions, it's probably better to post another question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

**Html**

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#" data-container-class="contact-info">Contact info</a>
  <a href="#" data-container-class="submission-methods">Submission methods</a>
  <a href="#">Data base</a>
  <a href="#" data-container-class="frequent-kick-codes">Frequent kick codes</a>

</nav>

<div class="contact-info" data-container>
  <p>Contact info</p>
</div>


<div class="submission-methods" data-container>
  <p>submission methods</p>
</div>

<div class="frequent-kick-codes" data-container>
  <p>frequent kick codes</p>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // initially don't show anything
  $('*[data-container]').hide();

  // Hide or show the div for that menu item. We don't hide the others because that wasn't asked.
  $('*[data-container-class]').click(function(e) {
    var className = $(this).data('container-class');
    $('.' + className).toggle();
  });
});
```

[Jsfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/ovge1rcd/6/)

Comment: So is there a way to lets say if I click submission info first then contact info? the contact info would show under submission methods div? if that makes any sense?